# Secondary user groups not loaded

Tags: permissions, users, session, groups

After the `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` run few days ago, user groups are not applied properly to the currently logged-in user.

I can see all the groups being properly saved in the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/groups` but after the system restart only the default user group is being applied. I don't see any particular errors in `syslog`.

After system startup only the default group is being applied to the user.

```
user@localhost:~$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user)
```

Though, when listing available groups they're visible but not currently attached to the session.

```
user@localhost:~$ id user
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),27(sudo),999(docker)
```

I need to manually login as the same user every time new shell session is created, then it works as expected.

```
user@localhost:~$ su user
user@localhost:~$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),27(sudo),999(docker)
```

Any ideas what could caused this?

---

I have already tried:

- Log out / in
- Recreate groups
- Reassign groups to the user

---

As a bonus I can mention that the `newgrp` behaves weird and it switches the main group instead of registering it with the others:

```
user@localhost:~$ newgrp docker
user@localhost:~$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=999(docker) groups=999(docker)
```

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem (xfce, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). A report on the [lightdm bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1781418) suggests removing/commenting out two lines in /etc/pam.d/lightdm, specifically:

```
auth optional pam_kwallet.so
auth optional pam_kwallet5.so
```

should become:

```
#auth optional pam_kwallet.so
#auth optional pam_kwallet5.so
```

This worked for me! I'm guessing that this might have some effect on auto-unlocking of your KWallet at login, if that's relevant.

Comment: This also prevented the "logout" function of the GUI from working. I would select "logout" and the GUI would exit and then reload itself, leaving me logged into the console. Removed those 2 from pam.d/lightdm, and logout now works.

Comment: This fixed it for me, that bug still seems to be current in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

A processes's group membership is set up once at login time, by `login`. The system does not track the group file and modify existing processes.

You can start a process with new group membership info with the `newgrp` command. Read `man newgrp`

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. Though I'm looking for a reason why after the system starts groups are not loaded properly. I can manually fix it by logging in as current user with `su user`. This is annoying as I need to do this every time new `shell` window is open. Before the packages update it worked as expected and all groups were loaded properly. I do expect this is some configuration error that happened during the packages upgrade though can not locate the source of the problem.